# Create vertical buttons using Bootstrap

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I want to create five buttons on my dashboard but what I currently have is not ideal. I would like to create five stacked buttons in one column.

```
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active btn-lg btn-block cari" value="all"> All</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active btn-lg btn-block cari" value="1">Site A</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active btn-lg btn-block cari" value="3">Site B</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active btn-lg btn-block cari" value="4">Site C</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active btn-lg btn-block cari" value="2">Site D</button>
                    </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please read the docs. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/button-group/#vertical-variation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="row">
                      <div class="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="all" Style="width: 200px;"> ALL</button></div>
                      <div class="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="1" Style="width: 200px;"> SITE A</button></div>
                      <div class="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="3" Style="width: 200px;"> SITE B</button></div>
                      <div class="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="4" Style="width: 200px;"> SITE C</button></div>  
                      <div class="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="2" Style="width: 200px;"> SITE B</button></div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Site A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Site B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Site C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Site D</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is for 5 grid column in bootstrap 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vertical button group feature provided by bootstrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/button-group/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```

try this and try to go to bootstrap documentation, you can find all in there.